# How can I create a schema which requires certain elements, allows others, and is order-agnostic?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to create an XML schema that contains the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="Record">
        <!--required elements-->
        <xs:element name="RecordTag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordSize" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordSection" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />

        <!--optional elements-->
        <xs:element name="RecordName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordDefault" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordComment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordURL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Condition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Master" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordCurrent" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="RecordId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can tell by the comments, I want the top three elements to be required, and the rest are optional.  The schema should allow for the elements to appear in any order.

Now, if I use the `<xs:sequence>` indicator, the order is enforced, which I don't want.
If I use the `<xs:all>` indicator, then the schema requires all the elements to appear, even if the `minOccurs` value is set to `0`.

Is there some other indicator that I can use to accomplish my task?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally <all> should fulfill your needs. CF: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_all.asp

Comment: If I use <all minOccurs="0">, how do I make it so the first three elements are still required?

Comment: @Blue: did you ever get an answer? or is this not possible?

Comment: I don't think I ever got an answer (on here at least), but if I recall I figured out how to do what I needed. Unfortunately, I no longer work at that company so I can't look up the source to my solution!

Comment: @Blue didn't you just use the use="required" attribute?

Comment: Like I said, I can't recall. Although the required attribute rings a bell. Fortunately I don't spend any time looking at XML schemas these days.

Answer (score 1):

Just for illustration, let's assume the XSD below; it is no different than the one provided in the post, except for being syntactic correct (by introducing the xs:all compositor) and, for easy creation of a sample XML, I've also added a dummy `Record` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Record" type="Record"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Record">
        <xs:all>
            <!--required elements-->
            <xs:element name="RecordTag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordSize" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordSection" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>

            <!--optional elements-->
            <xs:element name="RecordName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordDefault" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordComment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordURL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Condition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Master" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordCurrent" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="RecordId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>          
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Having this sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<Record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RecordId>RecordId1</RecordId>
    <RecordCurrent>RecordCurrent1</RecordCurrent>
    <Master>Master1</Master>
    <Condition>Condition1</Condition>
    <RecordURL>RecordURL1</RecordURL>
    <RecordSection>RecordSection1</RecordSection>
    <RecordSize>RecordSize1</RecordSize>
    <!--
    <RecordTag>RecordTag1</RecordTag>
    -->
</Record>
```

One would get this error message (when using .NET):

> The element 'Record' has incomplete content. List of possible elements
>   expected: 'RecordTag'.

Xerces would say:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'Record' is not
>   complete. One of '{RecordTag}' is expected.

All of the above is just a practical argument that the original statement in the question, which reads as below, is wrong.

> If I use the <xs:all> indicator, then the schema requires all the
>   elements to appear, even if the minOccurs value is set to 0.

The ask provided here is perfectly attainable in XSD 1.0 through an `all` compositor. There is nothing in the spec that would indicate otherwise; I venture to guess that a possibility might've been a  buggy implementation in the XSD aware XML processor.

Comment: So, what do you suggest? I have exactly the same problem. What is a workaround?