# Create an XSD that only checks for specific tags in any order

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Okay, I have read several similar questions on stack overflow and google but none seem to be the correct answer I am looking for...

We have several different clients that provide us XML feeds. We provide every client with a document that tells them, at a minimum, they must provide us an

```
<id>
<name>
<updated_at>
```

tags in each of the child nodes in their feed. Basically, we are trying to standardize the process. Each client will usually add in a bunch of other tags that are optional. We check if those tags exist and load the data if they do, and ignore them if the tag does not exist. Also, in the client feeds, I am trying to leave it open so they can deliver their feeds with the tags in any order... but honestly, I am starting to think that the solution to my issue is that part of the definition of a "standard" feed is for them to deliver the feed in a certain order.

Anyway...

So, for example, I might have a feed that looks like this for client A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<location>
  <id>10794</id>
  <name>Location Name 1</name>
  <short_name>Short Name for Location 1</short_name>
  <description>blah blah blah blah lots of test here</description>
  <image>http://www.myimage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/location1.jpg</image>
  <customattr1>30.3348048</customattr1>
  <customattr2>-81.6671269</customattr2>
  <updated_at>Mon, 03 Feb 2014 19:53:27 +0000</updated_at>
</location>


<location>
  <id>96</id>
  <name>Location 2</name>
  <short_name>Location 2 Short Name</short_name>
  <description>more long text for the description</description>
  <image>http://www.myimage.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/location2.jpg</image>
  <customattr1>30.3250000</customattr1>
  <customattr2>-81.6624480</customattr2>
  <updated_at>Mon, 03 Feb 2014 19:53:27 +0000</updated_at>
</location>

<location>
    ....
</location>
etc...
</locations>
```

And, then client B might provide us a feed like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<location>
  <id>10794</id>
  <name>Location Name 1</name>
  <short_name>Short Name for Location 1</short_name>
  <description>blah blah blah blah lots of test here</description>
  <updated_at>Mon, 03 Feb 2014 19:53:27 +0000</updated_at>
  <image>http://www.myimage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/location1.jpg</image>     
</location>


<location>
  <id>96</id>
  <name>Location 2</name>
  <short_name>Location 2 Short Name</short_name>
  <description>more long text for the description</description>
  <updated_at>Mon, 03 Feb 2014 19:53:27 +0000</updated_at>
  <image>http://www.myimage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/location1.jpg</image>     
</location>

<location>
    ....
</location>
etc...
</locations>
```

So, I have been tasked to write an XSD to provide to our clients so they can validate their XML against our XSD before providing us the feed. Currently, we have to customize every feed for every client.

I starting learning XSD and quickly discovered that if I use

```
<xs:all>
```

I can check for the required tags

```
<id>
<name>
<updated_at>
```

in any order, but I cannot use the

```
<xs:any processContents="skip" />
```

to skip all the other optional tags. If I use

```
<xs:sequence>
```

I can use the xs:any but now my required tags have to be in a very distinct order.

When using all, the XSD validated just fine,

```
<xs:all>
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>    
  <xs:element name="updated_at" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:all>
```

but, when I apply the XSD to the XML for Client A above, i get these errors
Error - Line 8, 19: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 19; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'short_name'. One of '{updated_at}' is expected.
for each

And when I create this XSD

```
<xs:all>
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>    
  <xs:element name="updated_at" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:any processContents="skip" />
</xs:all>
```

The XSD does not even validate and I get this error
Not valid.
Error - Line 12, 39: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 39; s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'all' must match (annotation?, element*). A problem was found starting at: any.

I have tried numerous variations with no luck.

Am I capable of checking for the 2 requirements listed below using XSD???

Requirement 1.

```
<id>
<name>
<updated_at>
```

tags are required (once and only once, I am using the minOccurs and maxOccurs but left out above for space since my post already seems excessive for what I thought was a very simple requirement) for each  and can be in any order.

Requirement 2. All other tags are optional and can be ignored

And if so, how in the world do I write that complexType???

This seems so simple to me and yet, here I am, 1 day later totally baffled. There is definitely much more to XSD than I ever imagined.

Thanks in advance for your recommendations.

In addition, this is one article I have already read and bookmarked related to using

```
<xs:sequence>
```

"How to ignore the validation of Unknown tags?", [How to ignore the validation of Unknown tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402452/how-to-ignore-the-validation-of-unknown-tags), So I don't think sequence is even a viable option for my scenario.

I read this article as well, [XML Elements in Any Order, Some Required and Others Aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902485/xml-elements-in-any-order-some-required-and-others-arent), the problem is my number of optional tags varies from client to client... I do not have a definitive number of optional tags, could be 0, could be 6.

This article was the closest to what I am looking for, [How can I create a schema which requires certain elements, allows others, and is order-agnostic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294740/how-can-i-create-a-schema-which-requires-certain-elements-allows-others-and-is). Four years old ;o(( wonder if XSD has changed much...

Answer (score 0):

XSD has indeed changed, there is now a version 1.1 which allows you, for example, to use xs:all content including xs:any wildcards. But be cautious; although the spec has moved forward, not all implementations have followed suit.

Answer (score 0):

We decided we are going to build the validation into our enterprise web app. Previously, we were going to point the clients to another web page and ask them to use that tool to run the validation using the .xsd we provide them.

Now, I have the ability to run an XSLT transformation on the client's XML. I can list all the required fields first in the order I want them and all the optional fields after the required fields, so, looks like I can now run the xs:sequence and run the validation for the required fields and ignore all the following optional field. I am not even sure I will have to run this step, as any missing tags will probably throw an error during the XSLT transformation and I can capture the errors there and maybe not even use the .xsd file.

This is my current plan. I won't mark any answers until I verified this works.